# DiffBind, diffferentially binding site

Tags: sequence-alignment, bioconductor, sequence-analysis, phylogenetics, chip-seq

I have data for 3 histone marks (2 for silencing and 1 for activation) each mark has three replicates.

when I run the `diffBind` package I have three contrast:

```
Silence1-Activation
Silence1-Silence2
Silence2-Activation
```

When I run dba.plotBox for any of contrasts I will have the same distribution of reads.like below:
[image: plotBox]
I even tried to start with 1000 peaks of each one that showed higher fold change but again got the same pattern for plotbox. How can I see which peaks belong to which histone marks?

Comment: most likely the data frame is wrangled wrongly. Even the outliers are the same. This is almost impossible

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from Rory Stark. the samples should have a unique ID. (https://support.bioconductor.org/p/132502/#132514)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Mariam